# Android class where i was wrong

Tags: java, android

```
public class temp 
{
    public int data0;//整数
    public int data1;//小数
    public int data2;
    public int data3;
    public long firsttime;
    public temp(int type,int data0, int data1, int data2, int data3,
             long firsttime) {
        super();
        this.data0 = data0;
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
        this.data3 = data3;
        this.firsttime = firsttime;
    }


}
public class ShareDate {

   public static temp mtemp=null;
   public static date mdate=null;

}
```

the problem is in `MainActivity` I did like this

```
ShareDate.mtemp.date0=20;
```

then the program was stopped unexpected. I don't know where it's wrong?

Comment: take a breath while editing @Krishnabhadra

Comment: Do you even create an instance of temp class?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, i am just saying you to do meaningful edit :)

Comment: what is mean ? i was use class ShareDate it in MainActivity ShareDate class include static temp mtemp. i mean  why i can't evaluation for mtemp.date0 ?

Answer (score 1):

where is your initialization code?

```
mtemp=new temp();
```

A class's object must be initialized to use its data member/Methods.

Comment: but mtemp is static  why it need initiaiztion?

Comment: you mean in class ShareDate? i was initialized as null ,then in MainActivity i still cannot  evaluation; like this  ShareDate.mtemp.date0=20;

Comment: oh thanks  your answer helped me ,now it's ok .it's must that initialize first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize before object use.. There is no initialization code..

```
mtemp=new temp();
```

And why u use constructor?

If you use ,

```
ShareDate.mtemp.date0=20;  like this ,,
```

no need a constructor.